# Equivalent english of Brazilian expression about trusting someone "by the mustache"?

Tags: expressions, portuguese

In Brazilian Portuguese, we use the following expression:

> Fio do bigode (*mustache wire/thread* or *mustache hair*)

Here's what I found after researching:

> It consisted of a man giving as a warranty, for his word, a thread of
>   his beard, usually removed from his mustache. Of controversial origin,
>   mustache may have come from the old German expression pronounced in
>   the oaths: "bi Gott", or "by God"

Example:

> O contrato entre as duas partes foi firmado pelo fio do bigode.

Which Google Translate readily translates to:

> The contract between the two parties was signed by the mustache.

The above expression means that both parties agreed to something without actually signing a written contract or equivalent. Basically, both parties trusted each other by the other's history/legacy/references/appearance/influence/promises or anything that might have transmitted confidence.

What would be an equivalent English expression?

Comment: "By the hair of my chinny chin chin." (from one of the Three Little Pigs)

Comment: answers so far find no equivalent ... passing something personal to seal the deal.

Comment: Does this only exist in Brazilian Portuguese or does it exist in original Portuguese? If it only exists in the Brazilian dialect I wonder whether it's origins might be in pre-Columbian culture.

Comment: @BoldBen I don't know.

Comment: Sometimes, a handshake agreement of the kind mentioned in some of the other answers is "sealed" by both parties spitting on their own hands before shaking hands with the other person. I've seen that done in some (fictional) movies although I'm not sure it was ever widely done in real life.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible expression is a **gentleman's agreement**:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   variants: *or* **gentlemen's agreement**
>   : an agreement secured only by the honor of the participants
>   //  That also ties into recent speculation that Chelsea have a *gentleman's agreement* not to pursue Napoli players.
>   — *SI.com*, "Chelsea Submit 'Important Offer' for Juventus Defender as Summer Business Finally Gets Going," 22 June 2018

---

These are sometimes legally enforceable, and sometimes not. It depends on the context.

In the age of knighthood and chivalry (at least according to its reputation in media  and popular culture), honour was a much more significant commodity than it seems to be today. Assuming that was actually the case, then saying *on my honour*, especially where witnesses were involved, would have been almost as good as actually signing something.

Comment: Considering the definition of "an agreement secured only by the honor of the participants", your answer seems to be the most spot-on so far to me. I will accept it.

Answer (score 3):

In the English-speaking world, we don't typically make deals by exchanging mustache hairs, but we do make deals with handshakes.

An equivalent expression could be *a handshake deal/agreement*.

> A handshake agreement is an agreement to do something based only on good faith, which cannot be legally enforced. Two partners might make a handshake agreement in which they both promise to work hard on a joint project. These types of agreements can significantly improve behavior in some settings.

[Knowledge @ Warton High School](https://kwhs.wharton.upenn.edu/term/handshake-agreement/)

> A handshake deal is a verbal commitment to a transaction. The actual transaction comes later, when documents are signed and money changes hands.

[Y Combinator](https://www.ycombinator.com/handshake/)

A more formal term of roughly the same meaning would be *an oral contract*.

Answer (score 1):

There are several phrases in English that might cover this:

A [***handshake deal***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshake_deal) or [***oral contract***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oral_contract) is one that is agreed to without a written instrument; under certain circumstances, U.S. courts have held them to be as binding as written contracts.

To say that ***one’s word is one’s bond*** ([definition from Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/your-word-is-your-bond)) ([definition from Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/my%20word%20is%20my%20bond)) is a somewhat dated expression that says that a person will always keep a promise once made.

Comment: Oral contract would not work: -- June 1890 The Irish Law Times and Solicitors’ Journal *“a verbal agreement is not worth the paper it’s written on.”*

Comment: @Greybeard - Only because there is no proof that the contract was actually made; in case of dispute, it becomes a question of one party's unsupported word versus the other's. I would suspect that other courts - in both Common Law countries (like the US, UK, Ireland) and in Civil Law countries (most of the rest of Europe) - have ruled that under some circumstances an oral contract - or 'handshake agreement' or '_foi firmado pelo fio do bigode_' or whatever the local expression might be - may be enforceable, and in others not.

Comment: @Greybeard - If both parties make the agreement in good faith, and perform according to mutual agreement over the terms such that there's no dispute, the oral contract is, in effect, usefully binding.

Comment: The "oral agreement" does not encompass the idea of "honour".

Comment: @Greybeard - _Any_ agreement that doesn't include a written instrument defining _all_ the terms, constraints, penalties, et cetera, _does_ encompass the idea that it is being executed by honorable people, acting honorably. It is only when the parties to the agreement disagree on the meaning of one or more terms etc., that adjudication need be involved, and the lack of an objective reference becomes a problem. So, yes, an oral agreement/verbal contract _does_, implicitly, encompass the idea of honor.

Comment: This shouldn't descend into an argument about law - in which we would have to consider "duress" and "undue influence", "utmost good faith" and "good faith", and "void" and "voidable". If there were no need for terms that included "honour", there would be no need for "gentleman's".